# Optimizing "this" type of loop

Tags: c#, optimization, loops, comparison, boolean

I'm currently (and have in the past been) using this loop to look through an array of custom classes and make sure that a boolean member value of each class in the array is equal. Is there a better (more efficient, simpler to code perhaps) way to do this?

Since that explanation is pretty bad and for lack of a better way to explain it, I'll simply ask, "Is there a better way to optimize 'this' loop?"

```
//set to true so the loop runs
boolean AllArentEqual = true;

while (AllArentEqual){
    //do some stuff to make stuff equal        



    ///// Check if stuff is equal /////
    //set to false to determine later
    AllArentEqual = false;

    //check if any aren't equal
    for (int i = 1; i < anArrayOfClass.length; i++){
        if (anArrayOfClass[i - 1].BooleanValue != anArrayOfClass[i].BooleanValue){
            //one isn't equal so set the loop to be re-run
            AllArentEqual = true;
        }
    } 


} //loop until stuff is equal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rework this a bit by extracting a method, and then potentially doing something like:

```
AttemptMakeEqual(anArrayOfClass);
while (anArrayOfClass.Any(c => c.BooleanValue != anArrayOfClass[0].BooleanValue))
{
    AttemptMakeEqual(anArrayOfClass);
}


// Extract out a method to:
void AttemptMakeEqual(YourClass[] values)
{
    //do some stuff to make stuff equal  
}
```

If there is a chance you may have "all equal" values, and you don't always need to run the operation *first* (ie: your new version), you could just do:

```
while (anArrayOfClass.Any(c => c.BooleanValue != anArrayOfClass[0].BooleanValue))
{
    //do some stuff to make stuff equal  
}
```

Comment: I've selected this one since it appears to be the nicest solution (in terms of neatness and looks) that actually works...

Answer (score 2):

An obvious minor improvement is the addition of a `break`:

```
for (int i = 1; i < anArrayOfClass.length; i++){
    if (anArrayOfClass[i - 1].BooleanValue != anArrayOfClass[i].BooleanValue){
        //one isn't equal so set the loop to be re-run
        AllArentEqual = true;
        break;   // We're done in this round
    }
}
```

Once it is established that not all are equal, there's no point in checking further.

Comment: Yes, I can add that in there to improve it; however, I guess I'm looking more for overall structure improvements...

Comment: Structure improvements would depend on how `//do some stuff to make stuff equal` looks. Unless it's short, making that its own function/method, as Reed Copsey suggested, would simplify the code. Of course it's possible that instead interleaving it with the check would offer possibilities for speedup, but if speed is not the concern, I'd support Reed's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd maybe do something like this:

```
class Widget
{
  public Widget( bool truthiness )
  {
    this.Truthiness = truthiness ;
  }
  public bool Truthiness { get ; private set ; }
}

class FooBar
{
  private Widget[] Widgets { get ; private set; }

  private Widget[] GetSomeWidgets()
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException() ;
  }
  public FooBar()
  {
    Widgets = GetSomeWidgets() ;
  }

  private void WorkOnWidgets()
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException() ;
  }

  public void MakeEqual()
  {
    bool areEqual ; // zero or one widget and it's not a problem
    while ( !(areEqual=CheckIfAllWidgetsEqual()) )
    {
      WorkOnWidgets() ;
    }
    return ;
  }

  public bool CheckIfAllWidgetsEqual()
  {
    bool value = true ;
    if ( Widgets.Length > 1 )
    {
      Widget first        = Widgets[0] ;
      Widget firstUnequal = Widgets.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault( x => x.Truthiness != first.Truthiness ) ;
      value = firstUnequal != null ;
    }
    return value ;
  }

}
```